# How to get coverage from external end-to-end testing

Tags: go, testing, instrumentation

We / Our QA teams use an external testing framework, cucumber on java, to write end-to-end unit tests for projects across various languages. We would like to measure code coverage from running such tests for our Go servers.

E.g. for our python servers, we:

1. Run servers using coverage:

```
coverage run ./src/server.py
```

2. Run the integration / E2E tests as a java application
3. Kill the python server after testing application is done
4. Generate test coverage reports using

```
coverage html
```

Is there something similar available on Go?
If not, what are the possible alternatives we should consider?

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43381335/13860

Comment: Indeed it does. Closing this question as it is a duplicate.